# Windows XP - DNS external domains does not work

Tags: windows-xp, dns

I have a DHCP and DNS server created in Linux and i have two machines: one linux and one windows xp.

In my Linux machine, dns is working for internal and external domains.

But, in my Windows XP, i can resolve to internal domain but to external i can't.

When i do `nslookup example.com`, i get:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\SRD>nslookup example.com
Server:  ns.example.com
Address:  192.168.1.3

Name:    example.com
```

When i do `nsslookup www.google.com`, it also works.

But, for example, `ping www.google.com` gives `Request Time Out` and, in the browser, i also cannot access to www.google.com

In my linux machine, everything is working fine. I can access to `www.google.com` without problems.

Comment: Have you configured the dns forwarding on the linux dns? Who is the dns for the xp?

Comment: Yes i have forwarding in dns. I want my XP to use 192.168.1.3 as DNS Server. I also configured that

Comment: Hhat is the result of `ping 198.252.206.140` (=www.superuser.com) on your xp? When it doesn't ping but the nameresolution `nslookup www.superuser.com` works, you have a routing problem.

Comment: ping gives `Request time out` but nslookup works

Comment: I check `route print` and the default gateway is 192.168.201.1, which is correct. But i cannot ping to it either. (In linux machine, it works fine).

Comment: the weird thing is that sometimes it works. Sometimes i can open google, but then i can't again

Comment: Is the linux a router between XP an your internet router? If yes, you have to add there the route back to your XP or use natting.

Comment: I have 3 machines: a linux server, a linux machine and windows. The server is where i configured the dns and dhcp for the other two machines. I'm connected to a network of the university and i have to use as default gateway the university router: 192.168.201.1
In both my linux machines i can ping for 192.168.201.1, but for some reason i can't do that on windows

Comment: you should edit your post and add your last comment. We also found out, that you don't have an DNS problem but a routing problem.